# Get Element Breaking Code

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to improve my Javascript by starting a simple web interface, but every time I try to add an event listener to an input field, it breaks my code.

Here's my HTML:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="colors.css">
        <script src="spot.js"></script>
    </head>

    <div id="ask">
        Search for an artist to see their top songs:
    </div>

    <form>
        <input type="text" name="artist" id="artist-search">
    </form>
    <div id="sub">
        submit
    </div>
</html>
```

And here's my Javascript:

```
window.onload = loaded;

var inField;

function loaded() {
    document.getElementById("sub").addEventListener("click", search);
    inField = document.getElementById("artist-search");
}

//https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=tania%20bowra&type=artist
function search() {
    alert();
    //var query = "//https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=";
}
```

When I add the getElementById to "artist-search", the alert in the search function stops working. Why is this? And is there a better way to get the text in an input field when someone clicks a submit button using vanilla Javascript?

Comment: Appears to work fine here https://jsfiddle.net/82835f8q/. What errors do you get?

Comment: onClick can be more useful for you.

Comment: No it's not @oguzhancerit